# Error using mex Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: macos, undefined, symbols, mex

Hello I'm trying to compile a code in c using mex command in a Mac 10.12.3  Sierra:

```
mex -v foldin.c -lmwlapack -lmwblas
```

However, I 've obtained in the vervose mode the next error:

```
Verbose mode is on.
Neither -compatibleArrayDims nor -largeArrayDims is selected.
     Using -compatibleArrayDims. In the future, MATLAB will require the use of
     -largeArrayDims and remove the -compatibleArrayDims option.
     For more information:
     http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.
... Looking for compiler 'Xcode with Clang' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'DEVELOPER_DIR' ...No.
... Executing command 'xcode-select -print-path' ...Yes ('/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer').
... Looking for folder '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'which xcrun' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/xcrun').
... Looking for folder '/usr/bin' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense' ...No.
... Executing command 'defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense' ...Yes ('8.2.1').
... Executing command '
agreed=8.2.1 
 if echo $agreed | grep -E '[\.\"]' >/dev/null; then 
 lhs=`expr "$agreed" : '\([0-9]*\)[\.].*'` 
  rhs=`expr "$agreed" : '[0-9]*[\.]\(.*\)$'` 
 if echo $rhs | grep -E '[\."]' >/dev/null; then 
 rhs=`expr "$rhs" : '\([0-9]*\)[\.].*'` 
 fi 
 if [ $lhs -gt 4 ] || ( [ $lhs -eq 4 ] && [ $rhs -ge 3 ] ); then 
 echo $agreed 
 else 
 exit 1
 fi 
 fi' ...Yes ('8.2.1').
... Executing command 'xcode-select -print-path' ...Yes ('/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer').
... Looking for folder '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'xcode-select -print-path' ...Yes ('/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer').
... Looking for folder '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'echo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk | rev | cut -c1-10 | rev | egrep -oh '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'' ...Yes ('10.12').
Found installed compiler 'Xcode with Clang'.
Options file details
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Compiler location: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    Options file: /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/maci64/mexopts/clang_maci64.xml
    CMDLINE200 : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.12 clang -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -bundle  -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map" /var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/foldin.o /var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/c_mexapi_version.o  -O -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"  -lmwlapack  -lmwblas   -L"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/maci64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lc++ -o foldin.mexmaci64
    CC : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.12 clang
    DEFINES : -DMX_COMPAT_32   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
    MATLABMEX : -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
    MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET : 10.9
    CFLAGS : -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk
    INCLUDE : -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/simulink/include"
    COPTIMFLAGS : -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG
    CDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    LD : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.12 clang
    LDFLAGS : -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -bundle  -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map"
    LDBUNDLE : -bundle 
    FUNCTIONMAP : "/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map"
    VERSIONMAP : "/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"
    LINKEXPORT : -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map"
    LINKEXPORTVER : -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"
    LINKLIBS : -lmwlapack  -lmwblas   -L"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/maci64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lc++
    LDOPTIMFLAGS : -O
    LDDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    OBJEXT : .o
    LDEXT : .mexmaci64
    SETENV : CC="/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.12 clang"
CXX="/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.12 clang"
CFLAGS="-fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -DMX_COMPAT_32   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE"
CXXFLAGS="-fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -DMX_COMPAT_32   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE"
COPTIMFLAGS="-O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG"
CXXOPTIMFLAGS="-O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG"
CDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
CXXDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
LD="/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.12 clang"
LDXX="/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.12 clang"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -bundle  -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map" -lmwlapack  -lmwblas   -L"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/maci64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lc++ -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map""
LDDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
    DEVELOPER_DIR_CHECK : 
    XCODE_DIR : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    XCRUN_DIR : /usr/bin
    XCODE_AGREED_VERSION : 8.2.1
    ISYSROOT : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk
    SDKVER : 10.12
    MATLABROOT : /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app
    ARCH : maci64
    SRC : /Users/jorge/Documents/Simulaciones/Simulaciones-Estatica/SIMULACION-ESTATICA/foldin.c;/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/version/c_mexapi_version.c
    OBJ : /var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/foldin.o;/var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/c_mexapi_version.o
    OBJS : /var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/foldin.o /var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/c_mexapi_version.o 
    SRCROOT : /Users/jorge/Documents/Simulaciones/Simulaciones-Estatica/SIMULACION-ESTATICA/foldin
    DEF : /var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/foldin.def
    EXP : foldin.exp
    LIB : foldin.lib
    EXE : foldin.mexmaci64
    ILK : foldin.ilk
    MANIFEST : foldin.mexmaci64.manifest
    TEMPNAME : foldin
    EXEDIR : 
    EXENAME : foldin
    OPTIM : -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG
    LINKOPTIM : -O
    CMDLINE100_0 : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.12 clang -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/simulink/include" -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG /Users/jorge/Documents/Simulaciones/Simulaciones-Estatica/SIMULACION-ESTATICA/foldin.c -o /var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/foldin.o
    CMDLINE100_1 : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.12 clang -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/simulink/include" -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/version/c_mexapi_version.c -o /var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/c_mexapi_version.o
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Building with 'Xcode with Clang'.
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.12 clang -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/simulink/include" -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG /Users/jorge/Documents/Simulaciones/Simulaciones-Estatica/SIMULACION-ESTATICA/foldin.c -o /var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/foldin.o
In file included from /Users/jorge/Documents/Simulaciones/Simulaciones-Estatica/SIMULACION-ESTATICA/foldin.c:2:
/Users/jorge/Documents/Simulaciones/Simulaciones-Estatica/SIMULACION-ESTATICA/fold.c:101:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'dgemm_' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            DGEMM(&transa, &transb, &i_len, &m_len, &l_len, &alpha,
            ^
/Users/jorge/Documents/Simulaciones/Simulaciones-Estatica/SIMULACION-ESTATICA/fold.c:84:16: note: expanded from macro 'DGEMM'
# define DGEMM dgemm_
               ^
/Users/jorge/Documents/Simulaciones/Simulaciones-Estatica/SIMULACION-ESTATICA/fold.c:279:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mxErrMsgTxt' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        mxErrMsgTxt("Sizes of folded indices do not match");
        ^
2 warnings generated.

/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.12 clang -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/simulink/include" -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/version/c_mexapi_version.c -o /var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/c_mexapi_version.o
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.12 clang -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -bundle  -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map" /var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/foldin.o /var/folders/1s/1bkm1bj15jd090r2jxl5t0gw0000gn/T/mex_9034902856557_5843/c_mexapi_version.o  -O -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"  -lmwlapack  -lmwblas   -L"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/maci64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lc++ -o foldin.mexmaci64
Error using mex
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mxErrMsgTxt", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in foldin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The _mexFunction is the following one:

```
void
mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *ndx1, *ndx1max, *ndx2, *ndx2max;
    if (nrhs != 6) {
    mexErrMsgTxt("Wrong number of arguments");
    }
    if (nlhs > 1) {
    mexErrMsgTxt("Too many output arguments expected");
    }
    ndx1 = mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
    if (mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[2]) > 1) {
    ndx1max = ndx1 + 1;
    } else {
    ndx1max = ndx1;
    }
    ndx2 = mxGetPr(prhs[5]);
    if (mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[5]) > 1) {
    ndx2max = ndx2 + 1;
    } else {
    ndx2max = ndx2;
    }
    plhs[0] = fold(prhs[0], mxGetScalar(prhs[1]), *ndx1, *ndx1max,
           prhs[3], mxGetScalar(prhs[4]), *ndx2, *ndx2max);
}
```

The problem is that the program fold.c is not mine and I don't know if there is a problem with the program itself or I have not use mex command appropriately. On the other hand I'm using Xcode 8 as compiler. Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem compiling code that wasn't mine. Just replace the occurences of `mxErrMsgTxt("bliblablu")` with `mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("xxx","bliblablu")`.

(see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexerrmsgtxt.html eg. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexerrmsgidandtxt.html)